# Can I mock the response of my request in chrome dev tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging the frontend issue which only happened in production. I am wondering if there is any way that I can mock the response of request or mock some static file.

For example,

When I call xxx.com, it loads `index.html` and `index.html` loads `a.js`.
Since chrome cache the js, is it possible that we can mock the `a.js` so that `index.html` will load the mocked `a.js`?

Comment: I remember I do something like that two years ago, but can't find the section area in the devtool anymore

Answer (score 26):

There is no way to mock a server response in devtool itself, but there are some chrome extensions helping with this:
I've tried 7 of them, but ( [Tweak](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tweak/feahianecghpnipmhphmfgmpdodhcapi) ) the only one was able to:

1. intercept needed URL
2. set the content-type type
3. set the payload

[image: tweak extension]

Comment: this extension is pretty useful! I have tried and it's and is really easy to use, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[As of Chrome 117, you can mock web content locally.](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-117/#network)

> To override web content, open the Network panel, right-click a
> request, and select Override content.

> DevTools currently supports content overrides for the following request types: images (for example, avif, png), fonts, fetch and XHR, scripts (css and js), and documents (html). DevTools now grays out the Override content option for unsupported types.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) using [`page.setRequestInterception()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) + [`request.respond()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestrespondresponse). Something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
      if (interceptedRequest.url() === 'https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js') {
        interceptedRequest.respond({
          body: 'document.title = "42";',
        });
      } else {
        interceptedRequest.continue();
      }
    });

    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/help');

    // await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is **npm json-server**.
It return stored json on each request for specified url